# Does `du /` list every single file on a system?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, debian, du

Does `du /` list ***every single file?***
 ||
Is there a better way?

Comment: A better way to do what?

Comment: A better way to *list* ***every single file..***

Comment: Every single file on a system?  Nah.  Every single file on all mounted filesystems?  Maybe...  While there may be little significant difference between those two things, on other systems the difference may be notably significant (and worth mentioning so that that other data isn't overlooked/forgotten).

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple StackExchange sites http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303635/133107

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been cross posted to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/303635/133107. Please read [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does `du /` list every single file?

From `man du`:

> Summarize disk usage of each `FILE`, recursively for directories.

<strike>I do interpret that as: yes, `du /` lists every single file under `/`. There may be some pitfalls I don't know though.</strike>

This will list files if they are given as arguments. Because `/` is a directory, `du /` lists directories; files are *taken into account* while calculating sizes of their respective directories; in this case they are not listed.

---

`find` is a standard tool to list files. To list every single file invoke:

```
sudo find / -type f
```

where `-type f` tells the tool to list regular files only. This way you get your output without the sizes (compared to `du` output); it's a good thing if you want only to list the files.

---

In general case `find` is useful because you can specify several criteria to it (the following list is non-exhaustive):

- should the results include regular files, directories, named pipes,… (`-type` option);
- by *ctime*, *atime*, *mtime*;
- by owner;
- by permissions;
- by size.

I guess you need to have a list of files in order to do something with it. You can use paths provided by `find` in a pipe, specify its output (`-fprint` option) or execute command for every file found (`-exec`). There are also options (like `-print0`) designed to avoid problems with some troublesome characters in filenames.

Refer to `man find` for more information.

Comment: This seems like a good answer... to the third question.  (Ignoring the first two questions, which are basically the same, including the question in the title.)

Comment: @TOOGAM This is because it seemed to me that OP assumed `du` to be a good solution to actual problem ([XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?). I may be wrong about OP's case but future users searching for "list every single file" should find `find`, not `du`.

Comment: @TOOGAM I have expanded my answer. Thank you for your remark.

Comment: Just ran `du` on an Ubuntu instance and only showed directories. 16.04 on AWS. But then again they were soft links made using `ln -s` which might be an important distinction. `find` returns these.